# Angular custom text search filter order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I would like to adjust my angular text search so that it isn't word-order sensitive.
I have to search a big json object but
basically if there `{"name":"John Doe"}` in the file, I want the `searchText` 'Doe John' to return positive.
Any suggestions? Thanks

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText">
       {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

i got it working thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/Lp02huqm/

Comment: Have you looked at `orderBy`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: You have to create a custom comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually created a similar filter for something.

```
app.filter("searchText", function () {
    return function (items, filterBy) {
        var filterBy = filterBy.split(/\s+/);

        if (!filterBy.length) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(function (item) {
            return filterBy.every(function (word) {
                return ~item.indexOf(word);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Note that I use `every`, so you would need "Doe John" for "John Doe."  If you wanted "Doe" or "John" to also match, you could use `.some`.

Comment: This is cool! Would you mind include an example of how to use this in html? It would be a little strange as `ng-repeat="item in items | searchText:searchText"`.

Comment: @runTarm just `| searchText`

Comment: thanks! the Array.every function was very usefull! here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/Lp02huqm/